# Checking for a null column in a csv file

Tags: grep, csv

I have a delimited file with the following syntax:

```
A|B|C|D|E
```

How to find the count of records having null (empty) value in their third column in every row?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F '\\|' '$3==""' file.txt
```

- `-F '\\|'` sets the field delimiter as literal `|`
- `$3==""` checks if the third field is null, if so it prints the record (default)

**Example:**

```
% cat file.txt
A|B|C|D|E
A|B|C|D|E
A|B||D|E

% awk -F '\\|' '$3==""' file.txt
A|B||D|E
```

---

Actually you don't need the escaping as when there is only one character is used as field separator, it is teated literally; Thanks to @Stéphane Chazelas:

```
awk -F '|' '$3==""' file.txt
```

Comment: Stéphane, thanks. I did not know that, edited.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
awk -F"|" '{if (length($3) == 0) ++count } END { print count }' yourfile
```